# Abelian groups axioms with minus in place of plus

Tags: abstract-algebra

An abelian group is a set equipped with a binary operation $+$, a unary operation $-$ and a nullary operation (constant) $0$, satisfying certain axioms (associativity, unity, etc).
I wonder if it is possible to describe the same structure, that is that of abelian group, using a binary operation $-$ and a constant $0$. I think it is possible by setting $a-b=a+(-b)$ where in the LHS there is the binary $-$ I am defining, while in the RHS we have the usually binary $+$ and the unary "inverse" operator $-$. But which should be the axioms for $-$ in order to have an abelian group?

Comment: @Alizter I think that plus is commutative, and minus certainly not, but I can't see why this should be a problem

Comment: @Alizter This is precisely what I am asking: if I use minus in place of plus, what will be new axioms describing the structure of abelian groups? What you are saying to me is simply: commutativity won't appear in the new set of axioms.

Comment: @alitzer because he wants an abelian group which described in terms of the$-$ operation. You can take a look at the answer to see what the question was asking.

Comment: Related reference: http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2307287?sid=21106391248673&uid=3738296&uid=2&uid=4

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Let $(X,-,0)$ be a triple consisting of a set $X$, a binary operation $-$ on $X$ and a constant $0$ in $X$. We will require the following axioms:

- $(a-d)-(b-c)=(a-b)-(d-c)$
- $a-0 = a$
- $a-a=0$
- $b-(c-a)=a-(c-b)$

Define $a+b := a-(0-b)$. I claim that $(X,+,0)$ is an abelian group.

It is clear that $a+b=b+a$, $a+0=a$, and $(0-a)+a=0$. Finally, $+$ is assocative: We start with
$$(a-0)-(b-c)=(a-b)-(0-c)$$
Substituting $b$ by $0-b$ and using $a-0=a$ yields
$$a-((0-b)-c)=(a-(0-b))-(0-c)$$
The right hand side is clearly $(a+b)+c$. The left hand side equals $a+(b+c)$ because
$$0-(b+c) = 0 -(b-(0-c)) = (0-0)-(b-(0-c))\\
=(0-b)-(0-(0-c)) =(0-b)-(c-(0-0))=(0-b)-c.$$
Thus, $(X,+,0)$ is an abelian group.

Conversely, if $(X,+,0)$ is an abelian group, then $a-b := a+(-b)$ satisfies the axioms. These constructions are inverse to each other. The notions of homomorphisms also agree, so that we get isomorphic categories.

Notice that it is possible to reduce the axioms and still make the proof work: In axiom 1, we may assume $d=0$. In axiom 4, we may assume $c=0$. But I think that the axioms look more natural when stated as above.

Comment: Technically, you don't even need zero, just an axiom $x-x=y-y$ and then use $x-x$ in all your axioms where you used $0$.

Comment: Not quite, since this would include $X=\emptyset$ (the same is true for Andreas Caranti's answer). And the axiom $X \neq \emptyset$ does not fit to universal algebra. Also, as explained in my answer, I didn't want to have some minimal system of axioms. It should be natural instead.

Answer (score 24):

There's [Tarski's famous single axiom for Abelian groups in terms of subtraction](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm30/fm30132.pdf):
$$
x - (y - (z - (x - y))) = z.
$$

---

See [here](http://www.cs.unm.edu/~mccune/projects/gtsax/) for a version by G. Higman and B. H. Neumann for groups.

Comment: Is this just a curiosity or is there any "use" of single-axiom descriptions of abelian groups or groups?

Comment: There probably isn't much use. It's more an intellectual exercise. I suppose a minimum size of axioms says something about the complexity of the system.

Comment: I agree if you mean not just "number" with "size", but rather something like "sum of lengths".

Answer (score 6):

Once you know that you can rewrite $a + b = a - (0 - b)$, it's simply a matter of going through the abelian group axioms and rewriting everything:

> An abelian group is a triplet $(A, -, 0)$ consisting of a set $A$, a law $- : A \times A \to A$ and an element $0 \in A$ such that:
>
> - Associativity: for all $a,b,c \in A$,
>     $$(a + b) + c = a + (b + c) \iff \color{red}{(a - (0 - b)) - (0 - c) = a - (0 - (b - (0 - c)))}$$
> - Identity element: for all $a \in A$,
>     $$a + 0 = a = 0 + a \iff \color{red}{a - (0 - 0) = a = 0 - (0 - a)}$$
> - Inverse element: for all $a \in A$, there exists $b \in A$ such that:
>     $$a + b = 0 = b + a \iff \color{red}{a - (0 - b) = 0 = b - (0 - a)}$$
> - Commutativity: for all $a, b \in A$,
>     $$a + b = b + a \iff \color{red}{a - (0 - b) = b - (0 - a)}$$

To get a "true" abelian group from this kind of abelian group, simply set $a + b = a - (0 - b)$, and you'll see that all the axioms are there.

Comment: That's true, but there are more "natural" axioms. See my answer (which will be posted soon).