# Properties of subtraction and division

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm (re)learning math and was looking for the properties of the most basic math operations. For addition and multiplication these are very easy to find (e.g. https://www.aaamath.com/g74a_px1.htm and https://www.aaamath.com/mul74bx2.htm. I also tried to find this for subtraction and division and there are some list of properties but i also found this: https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-different-properties-of-subtraction-and-division here some people answered:

> Addition and multiplication have properties, such as the commutative property. Division is actually multiplication of the inverse, and does not have its own properties. Subtraction is actually addition of a negative, and does not have its own properties.

and :

> Subtraction is addition in a negative, so it doesn't have its own properties.
> Division is multiplication of the inverse, and it doesn't have its own properties.

Is there any truth in this? If so how can I use this when doing/solving subtraction/division problems?

Comment: See [Addition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addition) as well as [Multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication) for basic def and properties.

Comment: With "Division is actually multiplication of the inverse, and does not have its own properties" the author of the quote simply means: due to the fact that division is defined in terms of multiplication, the properties of division are directly derived from those of multiplication.

Comment: But from a didactical point of view, it is probably better to introduce [Division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_(mathematics)) as a "basic" operations.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA thanks for the reply! So for learning purposes i should look at division an subtraction as basic operations but theoretically they are just multiplication and addition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to the addition operation, subtraction has its own
special properties but they are not as widely stated explicitly.
$$ 0 - x = -x.\tag{1} $$
$$ x - 0 = x. \tag{2} $$
$$ x - x = 0. \tag{3} $$
$$ x - y = -(y - x). \tag{4} $$
$$ (x - y) - (z - w) = (x - z) - (y - w). \tag{5} $$

There is a similar list in an answer to [MSE question 1225445](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1225445) "Abelian groups axioms with minus in place of plus".

Comment: Thanks for the list of properties. Do you have a source/website where these rules are explained further?