# Axiom Q in Fischer's Intermediate Real Analysis

Tags: abstract-algebra, real-numbers

In [Intermediate Real Analysis by Emanuel Fischer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01JXS7TC6) page 6, the author states an axiom that says

> (Axiom Q) If $x$ and $y$ are real numbers, where $z+y\neq z$ holds for some real $z$, then there exists a real number $q$ such that $yq=x$.

Is there a name for this axiom? I believe "$z+y\neq z$" is a typo; shouldn't it be $z+y\neq x$? Does anyone know if there is a list of typo for this book?

Comment: $z+y \neq z$ means $y \neq 0$. Such a $q$ only exist when $y \neq 0$.

Comment: @N.S. So, restating this axiom, it is exactly same as saying "If $x$ and $y$ are real numbers with $y\neq 0$, there exists ...."?

Comment: "there exists $\frac{x}{y}$"... This is basically the axiom that every non-zero element has an inverse.

Comment: @N.S. Thanks for your help. I've understood it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He's postulating the axiom that quotients exist for real numbers, with the necessary restriction that the dividend must be nonzero, i.e. it cannot be the addtive neutral element (usually denoted by $0)$.

Unlike the [most common axiomatization of a field,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics)#Classic_definition) the author does not include axioms for the neutral elements $0$ and $1$ for addition and multiplication. Rather, he defines the additive and multiplicative groups using axioms that differences and quotients exist, i.e. $\,a + x = b\,$ is solvable for all $\,a,b\in \Bbb R,\,$ and $\, a\cdot x = b\,$ is solvable for all $\,a,b\,$ when $\,a\,$ is not additively neutral (i.e. when $\, x + a = x\,$ fails to be true for all $\,x\in \Bbb R,\,$ i.e. when $\,r+a\neq r\,$ for some $\,r\in \Bbb R).$

Later he proves that there exist unique additive and multiplicative neutral elements, denoted by the customary symbols $0$ and $1$.

This axiomatization of groups using division (or subtraction) is less common than [that using inverses and neutral elements,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_(mathematics)#Definition) but it does occur from time to time (and if memory serves correct it has been discussed here in the past on multiple occasions, e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1225445/242)). In fact there are many known axiomatizations of groups, rings, fields. Typically we choose one that proves convenient for the context at hand.